# Python - OGR: Distance different than in ArcGIS

Tags: gdal, distance, ogr

I want to determine the shortest distance between a point and a line. I use the following Python script to do so. If I compare the result of the script with the result of ArcMap's Near Analysis, I get a completely different results. The shapefiles are in the CRS GCS_North_American_1983 and projected with Albers. What could be the reason for the difference?

```
import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

lineshp = driver.Open('U:/My Documents/Tool/shp/line.shp', 0)
linelyr = lineshp.GetLayer()

pointshp = driver.Open('U:/My Documents/Tool/shp/point.shp', 0)
pointlyr = pointshp.GetLayer()

line = linelyr.GetNextFeature()
point = pointlyr.GetNextFeature()

line_geom = line.GetGeometryRef()
point_geom = point.GetGeometryRef()

dist = point_geom.Distance(line_geom)

print dist
```

Comment: My guess is that one is the 2D Cartesian distance (likely the Near tool) and the other is the geodesic distance.

Comment: The distance is according to ArcGIS 500 m and accroding to Python(OGR) 29215.31 m. I don't think that the distance would be of such a big difference just because of that.

Comment: You are comparing the first features (FID=0) with OGR. Are you comparing the same geometries in ArcGIS?

Comment: @MikeToews: Thank's a lot. That was the problem. I compared only the first features. This solved my problem. If you want to post this as a answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why my distance was off, was because I only compared the first feature. This will solve the problem:

```
import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

lineshp = driver.Open('U:/My Documents/Tool/shp/line.shp', 0)
linelyr = lineshp.GetLayer()

pointshp = driver.Open('U:/My Documents/Tool/shp/point.shp', 0)
pointlyr = pointshp.GetLayer()

linefeat = linelyr.GetNextFeature()
pointfeat = pointlyr.GetNextFeature()

point_geom = pointfeat.GetGeometryRef()

distlist = []
while linefeat:
    line_geom = linefeat.GetGeometryRef()
    dist = point_geom.Distance(line_geom)
    distlist.append(dist)
    linefeat.Destroy()
    linefeat = linelyr.GetNextFeature()

print min(distlist)
```